# Returning a promise inside of another promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to return a promise that relies on another promises data. I think I'm mostly confused on how I should go about starting one promise right when the other one is done.

I end up getting

> Error on LDBManager.getRankByName: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

**index.js**

```
try {                   // DATA IS UNDEFINED HERE ↓
  LDBManager.getRankByName(name).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error on LDBManager.getRankByName: ' + e.message);
}
```

**ldb-manager.js**

```
var LDBManager = {

    getSummonerByName: function (name) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var url = LDB.url1;

            https.get(url, function (res) {
                var json = '';
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    json += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', function () {
                    var data = JSON.parse(json);
                    resolve(data);
                });
            }).on('error', function (e) {
                reject(e.stack);
            });
        })
            .catch(function () {
                console.log(`Couldn't retrieve summoner: ${name}`);
            });
    },

    getRankByName: function (name) {

        return this.getSummonerByName(name).then(function (summoner) {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var url = LDB.url2;
                https.get(url, function (res) {
                    var json = '';
                    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                        json += chunk;
                    });
                    res.on('end', function () {
                        var data = JSON.parse(json);
                        resolve(data); // ← DATA HAS WHAT I WANT HERE
                    });
                }).on('error', function (e) {
                    reject(e.stack);
                });
            })
                .catch(function () {
                    console.log(`Couldn't retrieve ranked stats for ${name}`);
                });
        });
    }
}

module.exports = LDBManager;
```

EDIT: Edited return, I can see the value I want in the resolve(data) but not in the console log.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `getRankByName` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Your edit, you still have a missing return.. `new Promise(` -> `return new Promise(`

Comment: Thank you @Keith, that's what I was missing.

Comment: `data` is `undefined` when you did handle an error with the `catch` - you don't return anything from there

Answer (score -1):

you need to wrap the getSummonerByName into a promise.

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    this.getSummonerByName(name).then(summoner => {
       // put your http request code here. then resolve data that you want to resolve from the promise resolve callback and reject if error occur.
    })
});
```

Comment: No you don't need to.